# VBA cannot get element and input data

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Here is the website that I want the data to be inputed: [website](https://www.icao.int/environmental-protection/Carbonoffset/Pages/default.aspx) Under"From City/Airport"

And i found the following HTML elements for that inputbox:

`<input name="frm1" class="frm1 col-sm-12 ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">`

Below is my VBA code:

```
Sub Data_Scrap()

    Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection, x As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.icao.int/environmental-protection/Carbonoffset/Pages/default.aspx"

    'Wait until the website is loaded
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")

    For Each x In HTMLInput
        If x.getAttribute("name") = "frm1" Then
            x.innerText = "hkg"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I also tried something simpler like `HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("frm1")(0).value = "hkg"` but it comes out with error:

> Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Could you clarify how to populate the result in that site, meaning the inputbox in which any keyword to input and any button to press?

Comment: **Three things and a question:** _**First**_ - The input tag is located in an iFrame. So the document of the iFrame must be accessed. _**Second**_ - To load the document of the iFrame, it requires another pause via `Application.wait()` or `Sleep()` after the parent document has been loaded. _**Third**_ - The form is based on JQuery, which can make things more complicated. _**So the question arises:**_ Which fields of the form must be filled?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, as i mentioned in the post, the inputbox i wish to be filled is "From City/Airport"